# Use .find nested in .map to build array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter, array.prototype.map

I have 2 arrays.

1) An array of ID's. ex. `item_ids: [1, 4, 12]`

2) An array of Objects

ex.

```
items: [
  0: {id: 1...},
  1: {id: 5...},
  2: {id: 12...}
]
```

I need to build a NEW array that consists of objects from the second array, `items` whose ID's are found in the first array.

In this case, it would be an array consisting of objects 1 & 3 since their ID's are present in the first array

Here is what I am currently trying but it's returning `undefined` for all three objects (there are 3 in the example I was using it in)

```
let new_avails = avails.avails_to_update.map(id => {
      this.state.availabilities.availabilities.find(function(a) {
        return a.id == id
      })
    }, this)
```

`avails_to_update` == id's

`this.state.availabilities.availabilities` == array of objects

Comment: The `filter` tag says you know you need to use filter. Have you tried anything we can help you debug?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The function `map` will create a new array with the same length of the original array.

Use the function `filter` instead along with the function `includes` to accomplish your requirement.

```js
var item_ids= [1, 4, 12],
    items= [{id: 1},{id: 5},{id: 12}],
    filtered = items.filter(item => (item_ids.includes(item.id)));

console.log(filtered)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Where's the love for `.includes`? Using `.some` seems like overkill.

Answer (score 0):

Due to [the nature of `Sets`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-set-objects): the following solution is less [`time complex`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity) than nesting [`Array.prototype.includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set/has) within [`Array.prototype.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter).

See and [`Set.has()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set/has) for more info.

```js
// Input.
const items = [{id: 1},{id: 5},{id: 12}]
const ids = [1, 4, 12]

// Filter.
const filter = (x, y) => {
  const s = new Set(y)
  return x.filter(({id}) => s.has(id))
}

// Output.
const output = filter(items, ids)

// Proof.
console.log(output)
```